# Java : Storing and updating HttpSession objects from a custom, application wide, Map

Tags: java, session

*(I do know that what we try to do is ugly. But we try to find a solution to fix something in a big legacy system... So please, no "Why do you want to do that?" here!)*

The application doesn't have a database that we want/can modify and we don't want to add any new dependencies to the project either.

Somewhere in the application, we need to get and update informations about a user and those informations are stored in his `HttpSession`. At that point of the application, we are not inside a user's request so we can't use `request.getSession()` to get the Session and the informations we need.

But we do have a "userId" so we were thinking about saving a reference to each active `HttpSession` in some kind of custom `Map`, using thoses "userId" as the keys. We could then access and update the informations we need about a user, without him being inside a request.

So let's say we store all new `HttpSession` objects in an application wide static Map (a `ConcurrentHashMap` for example). Do you see any potential issues of doing so?

For example, if a `HttpSession` object is serialized by the server (the application runs on a Weblogic server) and we update a Session object by retrieving it from this global `Map`, will the modifications still be there when the user is back on the site and the `HttpSession` is this time retrieved using `request.getSession()`?

In other words : what could go wrong by storing and modifiying the Sessions objects without getting them via `request.getSession()`?

Also : would there be any benefits of storing such kind of `Map` *as an attribute of the `ServletContext`*, rather than create it as a plain static Map on a class?

Answer (score -1):

The description resembles one projects I was part of couple of years ago.

> So let's say we store all new HttpSession objects in an application
>   wide static Map

Just to make it clear in terms of wording -- you do not store *objects* in the Map, you store (i suppose, strong) *references* to those objects. Exactly the same references you receive from map and via `request.getSession()`. So, I see no reason why updating those areas of memory (instances of object) would be invalid in any shape or form, should the reference be received from the Map or from anywhere else.

Sorry, can't comment on WebLogic's ServletContext

Comment: I think the Sessions objects can be (de)serialized by the container. Which means a *new* instance would probably be created when the Session is deserialized... So this new instance and the instance referenced in the Map would not be the same anymore... That's the kind of things I want to be sure of!

Comment: Well, this is technically possible. The question is -- whether or not those de-serialized instances will be linked (how?) to the `request`s? Besides, as far as I know, after session is generated (by first request of it), it's ID is assigned and never gets changed. Which means, even after de-serialization that ID  (object instance property) should remain the same.

Comment: @electrotype i believe you about to implement logic of HttpSessionListener and HttpSessionActivationListener